# How do I insert line breaks into a text file - not programming, not fixed width - via find & replace

Tags: text-editing, find-and-replace, newlines

This is a different from someone else's [similarly-titled question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490610/how-do-i-insert-line-breaks-into-a-text-file-im-creating-on-the-sd-card). Neither Excel nor OpenOffice allow users to specify line delimiters, so I'm trying to replace semi-colons with line breaks. How do I edit the code of a text file?

In Notepad I tried replace ; with /n.  I didn't think it would work; and it didn't. My long single-line txt/~csv file is crying:  Help!

Comment: So you dont want to do this programmatically? But you want to take a file with breaks indicated with semi-colons and change those semi colons to actual line breaks through find and replace?

Answer (score 3):

Using sed:

```
sed -e 's/:/\n/g' foo.txt
```

Comment: Is that a typo that you inserted a colon instead of a semi colon? Also that `-e` is not necessary in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that if you have Excel, you have Word....

You can add line breaks from the Find/Replace function in Word 2010 - make your CSV a .txt and go to town. Under Find/Replace click the "More >>" button and then the special drop down box to insert a line break as a replacement for "`:`"

You can also accomplish this with [NoteTab](http://www.notetab.com/); you would run a replace-all command, replacing "`;`" by `\r\n` -- but be sure to check the "regular expression" box.

"`\`" is a prefix to indicate regular expression codes and special characters. "`\r`" is a carriage return and "`\n`" is a line-feed; the pair forms a Windows newline.

Answer (score 0):

The best popular editor for this kind of task is [vim](http://www.vim.org/). You'll have some learning to do, so I won't get specific about the commands. It's an essential tool if you mess around with text files much.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Programmer's Notepad

1. Find what:  `<br />`
2. Replace with: `\r`
3. Click *Replace all*

Then repeat

1. Find what: `<p>`
2. Replace with: `\r`
3. Click *Replace all*

Then repeat

1. Find what:  `</p>`
2. Replace with: `\r`
3. Click *Replace all*

Answer (score 0):

I tried and succeeded doing it in Notepad++ which is a free application for Windows offered on Github. Please download install Notepad++ and copy paste your text with the `;` semicolons that need to be replaced with a "carriage return" or "new line".

Highlight the entire text and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, it will launch a popup called `Find`. Click on the `Replace` tab and type in your semicolon into the `Find what` slot, and type `\r\n` into the `Replace with` slot. Note you must click on the `Regular expression` button to highlight it. Then press the `Replace All` button.

If it does not work the problem is with the "semicolon" you typed into the `Find what` slot. Highlight any "Semicolon" in the text you want to replace and copy-paste that semicolon into the `Find what`. Proceed as before with the replacement steps. I had to do this twice as my text had some odd Unicode based semicolons that were not related to my PC keyboard strokes.

Eventually I got Notepad++ to do my `New Line` insert for all (25 Authors names in a book reference demarcated by semicolons) instances of the troublesome semicolons!